# Setting Thread Poolsize in Scrapy

Tags: python, multithreading, scrapy

How can I set the Thread Poolsize in Scrapy (python)?

Comment: scrapy doesn't a thread pool. You mean how to increase number of concurrent requests - there are a few settings that cover this in the docs.

Answer (score 5):

Since Scrapy does not use multiple threads and instead uses an underlying asynchronous http framework called [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/) you must be talking about how many spiders can you run at a time?  See the [CONCURRENT_REQUESTS](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#concurrent-requests) doc.
*Default: 16*